# I can't seem to get anywhere with installing ubuntu on a Windows 7 PC from boot

Tags: boot, system-installation, windows-7, livedvd

My workplace gave away some PCs after upgrading on the condition we wipe and install our own OS. I had hoped to leave Windows behind by installing ubuntu but having attempted to download and burn an install disc 3 times, the PC will not run it from boot. I have accessed BIOS to re-prioritise the boot order, putting CD to the top, and it attempts to run the DVD for a while then eventually reverts to Windows, which is tied to the old work network so I can't even log in. I also tried disabling all other boot options, and it just gets stuck on the manufacturer (Acer) screen. 
What is the first port of call for troubleshooting? The drive, the disc or is something deeper preventing this from working?
Any ideas much appreciated!

*UPDATE - after a long time hung on the Acer screen the system eventually went to a "DISK BOOT FAILURE, INSERT SYSTEM DISK AND PRESS ENTER"*
My guess is I'm not burning the boot disk correctly? What could be going wrong?

Comment: What class of PC (CPU, RAM, chipset) are we talking about, and which version of Ubuntu are you trying to install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely issue is how you created the boot disk, and which kernel it uses. This is a problem with trying to create the 'boot disk' on Windows/Mac (ie. not Ubuntu).

***Use a USB stick instead, and its much faster.***

The *cheats method* is ***Ask A Friend***. Get someone to **create** a USB boot stick on their copy of **Ubuntu**.

Otherwise, look it up. You need a Windows based tool that supports the version of Ubuntu you are trying to install, and a spare 2GB (or 4GB) USB stick.

---

Don't rely on boot-order, but instead use **manually select** boot device.

**Note:** *Start by setting BIOS back to the way it was.*

Comment: Perfect. I put the Ubuntu boot disk onto a USB stick and then manually selected the USB drive (having reset the BIOS defaults) during startup, and it has been a success; Ubuntu desktop is now installed and running beautifully. Thanks very much!